# JavaScript Carousel/Slider: How to add auto-transition of images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, carousel

I've hacked together some JavaScript code which allows the user to navigate through 3 different images (with content), by click the image number or using left/right arrow buttons. This works nicely but I want to add a function that will enable the slider to auto-transition through the content. I'm have jQuery implemented but not Bootstrap unfortunately. I had a tinker with ".interval" but didn't get anywhere. Can someone please assist? My code JS code so far is listed below:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){ 

        $("#home").click(function(){

            $("#about-page").fadeOut();
            $("#work-page").fadeOut();
            $("#contact-page").fadeOut();
            $("#menu").animate({width : "0px"});

          });


          $("#pag1").click(function(){

            $("#imageandcaption1").hide();
            $("#imageandcaption3").hide();
            $("#imageandcaption2").fadeIn();

            $("#arrow-left1").hide();
            $("#arrow-right1").hide();
            $("#arrow-left3").hide();
            $("#arrow-right3").hide();
            $("#arrow-left2").show();
            $("#arrow-right2").show();

          });
         });
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: To be more clear: I want to have the images change automatically (i.e. transition) at a set time/interval, if this is even possible.

Comment: please post your html also?